# SessionFactory setup in a Spring container

Tags: spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

The following excerpt from an XML application context definition shows how i tuned a JDBC `DataSource` and a Hibernate `SessionFactory` on top of it:

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.phoneBook.dao" />
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=phoneBook" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="a1f10g" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.phoneBook.model.Address</value>
                <value>com.phoneBook.model.Contact</value>
                <value>com.phoneBook.model.User</value>
                <value>com.phoneBook.model.Lang</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean  id="myProductDao" class="com.phoneBook.dao.Impl.AddressDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactoryBean" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

and based on this context i created my dao class,part of which is shown below

```
package com.phoneBook.dao.Impl;

 @Repository
    public class AddressDaoImpl implements AddressDao{ 
        private Session currentSession;
        private Transaction currentTransaction;
        private LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean;
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;    
        public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            return (SessionFactory) sessionFactoryBean.getObject();
        }

        public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }    
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactoryBean() {
            return sessionFactoryBean;
        }    
        public void setSessionFactoryBean(LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean) {
            this.sessionFactoryBean = sessionFactoryBean;
        }
```

but when i run my test i have NPE, can somebody explain me what i do wrong

```
@Test
public void addressTest(){
     AddressDaoImpl addressDao = new AddressDaoImpl();

     try {
         addressDao.openSessionWithTransaction();
         System.out.print(addressDao.findById(1).toString());
         addressDao.openSessionWithTransaction();
     } catch (DataBaseException e) {
         addressDao.closeSessionWithTransaction();
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Comment: please ass the packages to your code snipped

Comment: Use annotations or XML configuration. Not both

Comment: @Jens, i added packages

Comment: please post exception stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to autowire the AddressDaoImpl in you testcase:

```
@Test
public void addressTest(){

     @Autowired
     AddressDaoImpl addressDao
```

Or better use the Interface:

```
@Test
public void addressTest(){

     @Autowired
     AddressDao addressDao
```

Do not forget to run your test with:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath*:<your configuration>")
```

Because Autowiering only works in Container managed beans, not if you create your Bean with `new` keyword.

Comment: I cant add `@Autowire` to `sessionFactory`. i got this prompt - Could not autowire. No beans of 'LocalSessionFactoryBean' type found.

Comment: You should not add @Autowired to the `sessionFactory. You should add it to addressDao